# What are the catcode 11 / letter codepoints in Xe(La)Tex?

Tags: xetex, catcodes, naming

I'm trying to write a (JavaScript) RegEx to turn arbitrary sequences of characters into (hopefully) unique command names.

Part of the solution would be to replace everything that does not match `/[a-zA-Z]/` by something else, e.g. the empty string `''` or, for digits, `'1'` by `'one'` and so forth.

Experimentally I have found that while strings like `'辛亥革命'` and even `'一二三'` (that is, CJK digits) *do* work as legal names in XeLaTeX, neither `'¥ÄÖå'` nor `'、。'` do, presumably because of the respective first characters of these strings not being categorized as letters (catcode 11) by XeLaTeX.

So the question is: where are XeTeX's catcodes defined or documented? If I replace all Unicode codepoints that are not classified as letters—i.e. those not matching `/[\p{Letter}]/gu`—with something else, will all strings be turned into legal XeTeX names?

**Edit**: I'm fully aware that the resulting names may not be unique and that distinct filenames like `foo-bar.txt` and `foobar.txt` will both turn into `foobartxt` with a simple-minded elision of offending characters; however, disambiguation is not part of this question. That said, a solution that translates arbitrary sequences into unique names (hence allowing for roundtrip conversions) would also be interesting.

**Update:** I've come up with the below code; by going through a number of Unicode codepoints that are classed as `\p{Letter}` or `\p{Mark}` I found that the IPA Length Marker, `ː`, has a pleasant appearance *and* is a legal name character in TeX; it also is not treated as a word separator in my editor. I'm now using the below code to turn filenames into valid TeX names:

```coffee
@TEX_partitioner      = 'ː'
@TEX_latindigitnames  =
  0:    'zero'
  1:    'one'
  2:    'two'
  3:    'three'
  4:    'four'
  5:    'five'
  6:    'six'
  7:    'seven'
  8:    'eight'
  9:    'nine'

@TEX_text_as_legal_name = ( text ) ->
  ### See https://github.com/latex3/unicode-data; thx to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514731/128255 ###
  validate.nonempty_text text
  R = text
  ### replace Latin digits by partitioner plus name: ###
  R = R.replace ///[0-9]///gu,                  ( $0        ) => @TEX_partitioner + @TEX_latindigitnames[ $0 ]
  ### insert partitioner between sequences of lower and upper case (aB -> aːB) ###
  R = R.replace ///(\p{Ll})(\p{Lu})///gu,       ( _, $1, $2 ) => $1 + @TEX_partitioner + $2
  ### replace each code point that is not a Unicode 'Letter' or 'Mark' with partitioner: ###
  R = R.replace ///[^\p{Letter}\p{Mark}]///gu,  @TEX_partitioner
  ### turn the result into lower case: ###
  return R.toLowerCase()
```

Here are some examples; on the left, the original filenames; on the right, the symbolic names that are usable in TeX documents:

```
'Roboto-Regular.ttf'                  'robotoːregularːttf'
'Roboto-Thin.ttf'                     'robotoːthinːttf'
'sarasa-gothic-0.6.0'                 'sarasaːgothicːːzeroːːsixːːzero'
'ebas927.ttf'                         'ebasːnineːtwoːsevenːttf'
'Source_Sans_Pro'                     'sourceːsansːpro'
'OFL.txt'                             'oflːtxt'
'SourceHanSerifSC-Heavy.otf'          'sourceːhanːserifːscːheavyːotf'
'TH-Khaai-TP0.ttf'                    'thːkhaaiːtpːzeroːttf'
'UnifrakturMaguntia16.ttf'            'unifrakturːmaguntiaːoneːsixːttf'
'书法家超明体.ttf'                      '书法家超明体ːttf'
```

Given how difficult it is to come up with a naming convention in TeX that does not lead to hard-to-read spaghetti names with Roman numerals, I'm quite pleased with this.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the final macro names, note that you can create command names from arbitrary character sequences using `\csname...\endcsname`. The actual macro name can be obtained after exactly one expansion step then.

Comment: My experience in TeX has taught me to eschew any and all tricks when it comes to naming things, such as manipulating catcodes (beyond the standard way of temporarily allowing `@` in names). My objective is to find names to be used in, e.g., font declarations such as `\newfontface{\mktsFontfileːsunːextbːttf}{Sun-ExtB.ttf}[Path=\mktsPathsFontsHome/]`.

Comment: Is that for personal usage only? To me it seems easier to let a user write things like `\usefont{sarasa-gothic-0.6.0}` instead of a longish macro name which has a word separator character in it that is hard to type on many keyboards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Category codes in Xe(La)TeX ad Lua(La)TeX are both set by the script [`load-unicode-data.tex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-data), which picks up the code points from the Unicode Consortium. The script itself sets

- `\catcode` 11 for all letters (Unicode class "L")
- `\catcode` 11 for all combining marks (Unicode class "M")

Thus 'read `UnicodeData.txt`' is the best one can say here.

Comment: Great, that was the kind of pointer I was hoping for and that duckduckgo refused to come up with so far.

Comment: @JohnFrazer it helps that I wrote it!